# iOS: How to get my audio app to register in the multitask controls?

Tags: iphone, audio, avplayer

When a user double clicks the home button and swipe right, some audio controls shows.
How do I get use them?
I've searched but havn't found anything that helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {


    switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {



        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:

            [self playTapped];

            break;



        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:

            [self previousTapped];

            break;



        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:

            [self nextTapped];

            break;



        default:

            break;

    }
```

PlayTapped is the method for playing the music.
nextTapped is the method for the next song to be played.
previousTapped is for playing the previous track.

All the best

Comment: Why my answer is downvoted? Please reason it so i can understand where i went wrong.

Comment: Not by me! Thanks that is the solution, but I scrapped the idea since I am playing a mp3 stream. Not so many next/previous songs then.

Comment: Also is this the code for handling the button on the headset aswell?